# Cannot find tcpprobe in ubuntu

Tags: networking, iperf

I want to use `tcpprobe` to record the state of a TCP connections but I cannot find `tcpprobe` in `/proc/net`. Is `tcpprobe` not present by default? 
[tcpprobe](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/tcpprobe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load the kernel module tcp_probe with the command:

`sudo modprobe tcp_probe`

If you don't do this, the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

It is included. When you follow the [referenced procedure](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/tcpprobe) the `/proc/net/tcppdump` gets created (checked Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS, Ubuntu 15.10):

```
$ ls -l /proc/net/tcppdump
ls: cannot access /proc/self/net/tcppdump: No such file or directory

$ sudo modprobe tcp_probe port=5001
$ ls -l /proc/net/tcpprobe
-r-------- 1 root root 0 Apr 17 02:29 /proc/net/tcpprobe
$
```

Comment: I am not talking about `tcprobe`, its `tcpprobe`. http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/tcpprobe

Answer (score 0):

If loading it with modprobe still does not work for you (as it didn't for me with Ubuntu 18.4.4 LTS using Kernel 5.3.0-59-generic), you should know that at some point, `tcpprobe` was removed from the kernel. Check out [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1164634/1068484).

> tcp_probe functionality has been removed from the kernel. I believe, but am not certain, that its removal and the associated removal of some of the required infrastructure got out of sync. I am saying that even though the module is still present for `/lib/modules/4.15.0-55-generic/kernel/net/ipv4/tcp_probe.ko`, it doesn't work.