# tcp_probe could not insert 'tcp_probe'

Tags: tcp-ip, tcpdump

I'm Trying to Work with tcp_Probe, but I became this error:

ERROR: could not insert 'tcp_probe': Function not implemented
my kernel version is : 4.15.0-55-generic Ubuntu
 I have seen, that many people have the same Problem and I have to install another kernel, but I'm beginner and I don't know how can I install modules maybe at this version or how can I install new kernel and configure  boot, can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

tcp_probe functionality has been removed from the kernel.
I believe, but am not certain, that its removal and the associated removal of some of the required infrastructure got out of sync. I am saying that even though the module is still present for `/lib/modules/4.15.0-55-generic/kernel/net/ipv4/tcp_probe.ko`, it doesn't work:

```
doug@s17:~$ sudo modprobe tcp_probe port=5001
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'tcp_probe': Function not implemented
doug@s17:~$ uname -a
Linux s17 4.15.0-55-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 2 18:22:20 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Please also see [here](https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/865763/), which also tells you how to achieve the same thing using other methods:

> That function is now replaced by tcp/tcp_probe trace-event. You can
>   use it via ftrace or perftools.

By the way, the related kernel configuration parameter is `CONFIG_NET_TCPPROBE`:

```
doug@s17:~$ grep CONFIG_NET_TCPPROBE /boot/config-4.15.0-55-generic
CONFIG_NET_TCPPROBE=m
```

Answer (score 1):

net: tcp: Add trace events for TCP congestion window tracing
This adds an event to trace TCP stat variables with
slightly intrusive trace-event. This uses ftrace/perf
event log buffer to trace those state, no needs to
prepare own ring-buffer, nor custom user apps.

User can use `ftrace` to trace this event as below;

```
# cd /sys/kernel/debug/tracing
# echo 1 > events/tcp/tcp_probe/enable
(run workloads
# cat trace
```

source: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=c3fde1bd28f7c720d7bc587e85e54706df4f8163